# Can international students from Russia travel to Europe?

Tags: europe

I am a Sri Lankan student studying in Russia. Can I travel to Europe for 2 weeks during my vacation? If so, what are the requirements? Please explain what needs to be done from my end.

Comment: As with all travel, you'll need an appropriate visa; check also that your student visa allows you to leave Russia and return. What you need will depend on where you're going, so pick a destination and see whether Sri Lankans need a visa to go there. Note that many countries in the European Union are part of the [Schengen area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area), which effectively counts as a single country for visa purposes.

Comment: Without focusing on a particular country, this question is probably too broad to be answered effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to visit Schengen member states in the EU then you should apply for a visa from the country you intend to arrive in first. A commercial company runs an application office under contract to several member states for example http://www.vfsglobal.com/germany/russia/moscow/english/Common_Information_Sheet.html
You will need to show that you can afford your trip and that you have good reason to leave at the end.